# India and Egypt: What enables a culture to endure?

Tags: cultural-history, ancient-egypt, indian

What traits exist in Indian Hindu culture to allow it to persevere to the present day that did not exist in Egypt from ~3100 BCE to ~30 BCE?

EDIT by Alex: What destroyed Egyptian civilization?

Alexander's conquest?
Roman takeover? Introduction of Christianity? Muslim conquest? Some kind of ``natural death"? What else?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: The only way I can think that this question would make sense would be if you are talking about their respective ancient polytheistic religions.

Comment: Which Indian culture? which Egyptian culture? What evidence do you have that Egyptian culture did not survive? What evidence do you have that Indian culture has survived? What research have you done?

Comment: Alexander the Great?

Comment: Very interesting question. Unfortunately, answering it would get me banned.

Comment: @Tyler Durden: I am very interested to read your answer. My answer is that Egyptian culture was wiped out, and neither Alexander nor Ptolemy's nor Romans are responsible. Christianity and Islam.

Comment: @jamesqf: No. Most definitely no.

Comment: I think there is an interesting question here. I edited the question.

Comment: I still think this question is a bit too vague. What parts of Egyptian culture are we talking about? Their polytheistic religion? Their language?

Comment: @Alex: Why not?  Seems as though Alexander and his heirs at least started the process, replacing (or admixing) Egyptian culture with Greek, which some centuries later took a blow from the Romans, followed by the Christians until, if there was anything Egyptian left besides piles of stone, the Muslims delivered the coup de grace.  India didn't really have those repeated foreign conquests, other than the Muslims in the north, until the British came along.

Comment: @jamesqf the Mughals spread over most of the sub continent: north and central, and only didn't reach some of the south.

Comment: @Alex.  Still too vague -- what is meant by Indian and Egyptian culture -- but that's a good first step.  The change asks a "compare this to that" question, but as written it's still kinda broad.  removed my first comment as the question has changed.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: They may have been there temporarily, but they didn't hold it long enough to obliterate the Hindu culture, as they did in the areas that are now (roughly) Pakistan & Bangladesh.  You might compare it to e.g. the invasion/conquest of Egypt by the Hyksos.

Comment: Egypt was destroyed by the second millenia BC cooling. In general, southern hemisphere populations peak relative to northern populations in periods of warm weather. These climate cycles tracked the roman, islamic, chinese, and many other empires. The apparent extreme longevity of many of these civilizations may be due to the lack of records and assumption that any gaps represented a continuous dynasty.